# Closing previous instance of Constructor JAVA

Tags: java

My program displays an UI and updates a **JLabel** according to the user given input.

**My Code:-**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{ 
 createUI();
}

public void createUI()
{
 // creates the UI using JSwing
 // takes userinput from textfield and stores it in variable:- path.
 // The UI is updated on the click of button.

 JButton bu = new JButton("Search");
 bu.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
        finder mm= new finder(path);
        String namefomovie = mm.find("Title");
        //nameb is a Jlabel in the UI   
        nameb.setText(namefomovie);

}
}
```

**finder class:-**

```
public class finder
{
 static String metadata="";

 public finder(String path) throws FileNotFoundException
 {


     File myfile = new File(path);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(myfile);

        while(s.hasNextLine())
            metadata+=s.nextLine()+"\n";

 }

 public String find(String info)
 {
     //finds the required info stored in metadata and return the answer.
      return ans;
 }
 }
```

**Problem:-**

During execution, the UI is created and I give the input and all the methods are called and performed and the JLabel is changed the first time.

But when I give input second time and click on search button, the Jlabel's text remains same.

**finder** constructor creates a metadata according to the given input, so if a user is giving input multiple time, multiple instances of the constructor is going to be initiated.

Now I did some debugging and found that during the second time, the previous constructor's metadata is still in the memory along with the new metadata.

So the output of the `mm.find("title");` the second time is the same output we got the first time.

Please help me fix this and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`static String metadata`

Your metadata member is static, which is the reason why all instances of that class see and update the same copy of that member.

Your constructor of `finder` appends to the static member - `metadata+=s.nextLine()+"\n";`. Therefore the data appended by previous constructor calls is still there.

If you wish each instance of `finder` to have different `metadata`, remove the `static` keyword.